# Order result of query with the order of IN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, that will return me the ids of the favorited audios by the user, ordered by the date when they marked that ID as favorite:

```
SELECT audio_id FROM favorites
WHERE user_id = ?
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

Now, I try to display those audios in the screen, ordered also by date

```
SELECT * FROM audios
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT audio_id FROM favorites
    WHERE user_id = ?
    ORDER BY `time` DESC
    )
AND status = '1'
```

But after that query they are not ordered by date. The order of the IDs in the second query is not the same order of the IDs in the first one.

What can I do ? I don't want to store the result and then re-order it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it is not ordered by time is because your `ORDER BY` is in the inner `SELECT` statement. so it does not apply to the outer `SELECT`

This should work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM   audios AS A INNER JOIN 
       favorites AS F ON A.id = F.audio_id AND F.user_id = ? AND A.status = '1'
ORDER BY F.[time] DESC
```

Comment: Awesome!! Works perfectly. I've never learned to use JOIN. Always thought it was too hard to learn for me haha

Comment: @Zerquix18 good to hear man. This should help you with understanding joins http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Zerquix18 if the answer worked could you please mark it as answered thanks :)

Comment: Yes I was just waiting to see if other people share their own solutions, so future guests can see them all and choose one. But I'll do it now. Thanks you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` on the query in the `WHERE` clause does not have an impact on the data in the `SELECT` statement.  Making the query a join, allows the data to be stored in it's current location, and still be able to sort accordingly.

```
SELECT  A.*, 
        f.[time]
FROM audios A INNER JOIN favorites f
        ON A.audio_id = f.audio_id 
WHERE   a.status = '1' and
        f.user_id = ?
ORDER BY [time] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `ORDER BY` clause out of the subquery, just like:

```
select t1.* from audio t1
inner join favorite t2
  on t1.audio_id = t2.audio_id
order by t2.dt_date desc;
```

Try this on this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca05bf